# VB.NET single quotation not accepted by query

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I have a database class. And I'm using SQLServerCe which will run all commands. I put my query into a string variable q. And pass into the function of Database class. I have a problem. All values are accepted. But when I put single quotation into textbox. Then it gives an error.....

Here is my code :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
    Dim q As String = "insert into student_classes (student_class) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "')" 
    db.execute(q) 
    MsgBox("Record Added Successfully") 
    TextBox1.Clear() 
End Sub
```

Comment: Suppose I have entered string son's.... it give this error:
Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 59,Token in error = s

Comment: can you write the code that you wrote

Comment: My guess is replace single quote with three single quotes.

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim q As String = "insert into student_classes (student_class) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
        db.execute(q)
        MsgBox("Record Added Successfully")
        TextBox1.Clear()
    End Sub

Comment: I don't want to replace it with anything. So, any other idea?

Comment: In PHP we use mysql_real_escape_string function... Like that function, we have any other choice like that? because when you have more textboxes then you will find and replace. it will take time to execute....

Comment: SQL Server, and the .Net client libraries, do not offer this. However, parameterized queries/commands are the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this function on all field assignments that may contain '

```
Function EscapeQuote(ByVal msData As Object) As String
    Return (Replace(msData, "'", "''"))
End Function

e.g.  values ('" & EscapeQuote(TextBox1.Text) & "')"
```

Comment: I don't want to escape. And can't use parameterized query If yes how I can use parameterize query. Because I'm using Database Class. And everything done by that class. In my hand only pass a string into that function. Where I should use Parameterize query. Because In other forms I have more than one textbox. It may be 10-20 textboxes. So what should I do?

Comment: Working Fine thanks.... Please tell me... that can somebody put injection ????? If I will use this function???

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice but to escape the input or use parameterized queries/commands. The user can type or paste into TextBox1. Also, this is a SQL Injection attack vector. A malicious person could easily type something into that box and wreak havoc on your database.

Your code:

```
Dim q As String = "insert into student_classes (student_class) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
```

Let's say I type

> Smith

into the box.

Now, the value of q is:

> insert into student_classes (student_class) values ('Smith')

All is well with the world.

Now, let's say, instead of Smith, I type:

> Smith'); DROP TABLE student_classes; --

Your new query is:

> insert into student_classes (student_class) values ('Smith'); DROP
>   TABLE student_classes; --')

You may have just lost your student_classes table. Do not trust user input.

Comment: If DROP TABLE doesn't sound plausible, think about DELETE. A lot of client app logins have the basic CRUD permissions.